# Flutter : How to fix 'Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1'?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I just started using flutter on vscode and the Android emulator is connected to vscode. when I run the first flutter code by pressing f5 is not running, and on the console it says:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Samsung in debug mode...
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1
Exited (sigterm)
```

when I run it using intellij sometimes it works and sometimes it fails like the problem above. how do you solve the problem with vscode? intellij is too heavy for my computer.

Comment: Can you post your flutter.gradle

Comment: I have found a solution by updating the gradle version, thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a grade problem, and could be hard for you to debug without getting sufficient info on the problem
cd into your `android` directory 
then 
run `./gradlew build`
you should be able to get the cause of the failed build

Comment: I have found a solution by updating the gradle version, thanks for the response :)